# UITableView: reorder cells programmatically, animated

Tags: ios, uitableview

User can reorder / move cells in `UITableView` by dragging them if edit mode is set. Is it possible make this reordering, have this visual effect triggered programmatically? So not deleting first row with user interaction, and inserting the third, but start moving moving from code as finger would drag cell?

[image]

Comment: not getting your question properly! Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: It is not clear. Can you please elaborate your requirement  more

Comment: Wants do from code, see the same animation what user does with his finger, "drag", move cell from source to destination while floating over other cells.